# Error while authenticating

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a problem in my Ruby on Rails code:

```
 class SessionsController < ApplicationController
      def new
    @title = "Sign in"
    end
    def destroy
    end
    def create
    user = User.authenticate(params[:session][:email],
    params[:session][:password])
    if user.nil?
    flash.now[:error] = "Invalid email/password combination."
    @title = "Sign in"
    render 'new'
    else
    sign_in user
    redirect_to user
    end
    end
    def destroy
    sign_out
    redirect_to root_path
    end
    end
```

Error message:

```
private method `has_password?' called for #<User:0xb729d558>
app/models/user.rb:72:in `authenticate'
app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:8:in `create'
```

How might I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

For user authentication I suggest you to use gems.Below are the gems I prefer for my development.Friend I think this will help.

[Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)

[Authlogic](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic)

Also visit

[Rails authentication](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_authentication)